# Can't see the prints from the map tasks

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have set `mapred-site.xml` [1] and the `log4j.properties` [2] to show debug log files, and I have set my map class [3] `System.out.printlns`, but I don't see this getting printed. I have looked to the logs of the hadoop, or the log of the tasks, but I don't see nothing from the map tasks getting printed. I don't understand why I am getting this. Any help?

[1] mapred-site.xml

```
    ~/Programs/hadoop$ cat etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

    <configuration>
    (...)
     <property> <name>mapreduce.map.log.level</name> <value>DEBUG</value> </property>
    </configuration>
```

[2] log4j.properties

```
    hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG,console
    hadoop.log.dir=.
    hadoop.log.file=hadoop.log

    # Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
    log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}, EventCounter

    # Logging Threshold
    log4j.threshold=ALL

    # Null Appender
    log4j.appender.NullAppender=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

    #
    # Rolling File Appender - cap space usage at 5gb.
    #
    hadoop.log.maxfilesize=256MB
    hadoop.log.maxbackupindex=20
    log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

    log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.log.maxfilesize}
    log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.log.maxbackupindex}

    log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

    # Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
    log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
    # Debugging Pattern format
    #log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


    #
    # Daily Rolling File Appender
    #

    log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

    # Rollver at midnight
    log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

    # 30-day backup
    #log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=30
    log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

    # Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
    log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
    # Debugging Pattern format
    #log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


    #
    # console
    # Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this 
    #

    log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
    log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n

    #
    # TaskLog Appender
    #

    #Default values
    hadoop.tasklog.taskid=null
    hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup=false
    hadoop.tasklog.noKeepSplits=4
    hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
    hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
    hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12

    log4j.appender.TLA=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogAppender
    log4j.appender.TLA.taskId=${hadoop.tasklog.taskid}
    log4j.appender.TLA.isCleanup=${hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup}
    log4j.appender.TLA.totalLogFileSize=${hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize}

    log4j.appender.TLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.TLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

    #
    # HDFS block state change log from block manager
    #
    # Uncomment the following to suppress normal block state change
    # messages from BlockManager in NameNode.
    #log4j.logger.BlockStateChange=WARN

    #
    #Security appender
    #
    hadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender
    hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize=256MB
    hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex=20
    log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hadoop.security.logger}
    hadoop.security.log.file=SecurityAuth-${user.name}.audit
    log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
    log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
    log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
    log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize}
    log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex}

    #
    # Daily Rolling Security appender
    #
    log4j.appender.DRFAS=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
    log4j.appender.DRFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
    log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
    log4j.appender.DRFAS.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

    #
    # hadoop configuration logging
    #

    # Uncomment the following line to turn off configuration deprecation warnings.
    # log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN

    #
    # hdfs audit logging
    #
    hdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
    hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
    hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=${hdfs.audit.logger}
    log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=false
    log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit.log
    log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
    log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize}
    log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

    #
    # mapred audit logging
    #
    mapred.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
    mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
    mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=${mapred.audit.logger}
    log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=false
    log4j.appender.MRAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/mapred-audit.log
    log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
    log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize}
    log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

    # Custom Logging levels

    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=DEBUG

    # Jets3t library
    log4j.logger.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service=ERROR

    # AWS SDK & S3A FileSystem
    log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=ERROR
    log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient=ERROR
    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem=WARN

    #
    # Event Counter Appender
    # Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
    #
    log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter

    #
    # Job Summary Appender 
    #
    # Use following logger to send summary to separate file defined by 
    # hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file :
    # hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=DEBUG,JSA
    # 
    hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
    hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file=hadoop-mapreduce.jobsummary.log
    hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize=256MB
    hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex=20
    log4j.appender.JSA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.JSA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file}
    log4j.appender.JSA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize}
    log4j.appender.JSA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex}
    log4j.appender.JSA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.JSA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger}
    log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=false


    log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger}
    log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=false
    log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file}
    log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxFileSize=256MB
    log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxBackupIndex=20
    log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

[3] My map class:

```
    static abstract class SampleMapBase
            extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
        private long total;
        private long kept = 0;
        private float keep;

        protected void setKeep(float keep) {
            this.keep = keep;
        }

        protected void emit(Text key, Text val, OutputCollector<Text,Text> out)
                throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Key: " + key.toString() + " Value: " + val.toString());
            System.out.println("Key: " + key.getClass() + " Value: " + val.getClass());
            ++total;
            while((float) kept / total < keep) {
                ++kept;
                out.collect(key, val);
            }
        }
    }


    public static class MySampleMapper extends SampleMapBase{
        String inputFile;

        public void setup(Context context) {
            this.inputFile = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();
            setKeep(context.getConfiguration().getFloat("hadoop.sort.map.keep.percent", (float) 100.0) / (float) 100.0);
        }

        public void map(Text key, Text val,
                        OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            emit(key, val, output);
            System.out.println("EMIT");
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(new Configuration(), args);

        String[] otherArgs = parser.getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: webdatascan -Dfile.path=<path> [<in>...] <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        System.setProperty("file.path", parser.getConfiguration().get("file.path"));
        List<String> remoteHosts = new ArrayList<String>();// directory where the map output is remotely
        remoteHosts.add(Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());

        // first map tasks
        JobConf conf = MyWebDataScan.addJob(1, true, true);

        Job job = new Job(conf, conf.getJobName());
        job.setJarByClass(MyWebDataScan.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(MySampleMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MySampleReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        Path[] inputPaths = new Path[otherArgs.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) { inputPaths[i] = new Path(otherArgs[i]); }
        Path outputPath =  new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, inputPaths);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, outputPath);
        job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.output.dir", outputPath.toString());

        JobClient.runJob(job);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up old API and new API. Your input and output format classes use classes from new API, but your map function is specified in the form of old API. If you have imported org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.mapper, then map function should have specification like this

```
private static class RecordMapper
extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable lineOffset, Text record, Context output)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        output.write(new Text("Count"), new LongWritable(1));
    }

}
```

As you are using map function like this, the map function will never invoked. Instead it will use default map function as explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXXZwQex11Q&list=PLf0swTFhTI8p7ZYBB5DmRHK3L6aq8Mvcv&index=3)

```
public void map(Text key, 
                Text val, 
                OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, 
                Reporter reporter) 
    throws IOException
```